# Replace asterisk with nothing in string

Tags: tables, strings, substitution

I have a function which grabs cells out of a table and returns them.  Many of these cells end with two asterisks, and I would not like these returned from the function if they are present.  For example:

```
% Function to get data
\def\getdata#1#2{%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{#2}\of{\table}\pgfplotsretval%
}
```

If this returns a value such as "2.3**", I would like "2.3".  Thanks, I assume this is rather straightforward.

Comment: I'm sure someone will come up with a LaTeX solution.  But in the mean time, I'd approach this with a shell script in perl or ruby or something that can use regular expression replacement and run the data through the shell script first.

Comment: That could be good -- I want the tables themselves to have the asterisks in them though. I also have no idea how to do that.

Comment: If you provide a sample of how the data is formatted, I could try to write up a perl script.

Comment: You could also use the [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package and the `\StrDel{<text that has * removed>}{*}` macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) offers a possibility to ignore a list of characters while the data is being read from the table via `ignore chars={}` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age
Alb*ert,Einstein**,133
Marie**,Curie,145
Thomas,Edis**on,165**
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,ignore chars={*}]{scientists.csv}\mytable
\def\getcell#1#2#3{%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{#2}\of{#3}\pgfplotsretval%
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    string type,
    columns/name/.style={column name=Name, column type={|l}},
    columns/surname/.style={column name=Surname, column type={|l}},
    columns/age/.style={column name=Age, column type={|c|}},
    every head row/.style={before row=\hline,after row=\hline},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]\mytable

\bigskip
\getcell{0}{name}{\mytable} \getcell{0}{surname}{\mytable} is \getcell{0}{age}{\mytable} 
years old. \getcell{1}{name}{\mytable} \getcell{1}{surname}{\mytable} is 
\getcell{1}{age}{\mytable} years old. But \getcell{2}{name}{\mytable} 
\getcell{2}{surname}{\mytable} is still older, he is \getcell{2}{age}{\mytable} years old.
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, one should be careful since this method eats every instance of asterisk. For example `Alb*ert` is also modified. So one must be careful (x2).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! To be clear (might want to update answer), the intention was to have the asterisks in the table, but not the text, so my solution was to just read in the table twice, one being \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,ignore chars={*}]{scientists.csv}\nostartable

Comment: @mike That's a totally different question :) I would just use `xstring` package with String Substitution commands.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure someone will come up with a LaTeX solution. But in the mean time, I'd approach this with a shell script in perl or ruby or something that can use regular expression replacement and run the data through the shell script first.

Here's a shell script (in perl) that will strip off `*`.  Save this script in a file and call it `script.pl`.   I'll assume that the name of the data file is `data.txt`. At the command prompt, run

```
$ perl script.pl data.txt
```

This will print the reformated data to the console.  To capture this in another file:

```
$ perl script.pl data.txt > reformatted_data.txt
```

That way you still have the original to do with as you wish and the data without the astricks.

Here's the perl script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict 'vars';
&MAIN(@ARGV);
sub MAIN {
   my ($filehandle) = @_;
   open FILE, "<$filehandle";
   my @filecontents = <FILE>;
   close FILE;

   foreach my $line ( @filecontents ){
      $line =~ s/\*//g;
      print $line;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not really what the OP wants, but `sed -i 's/\*//g' data.txt` does the equivalent of your perl script in one line.